# Using Javascript's atob to decode base64 doesn't properly decode utf-8 strings

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8

I'm using the Javascript `window.atob()` function to decode a base64-encoded string (specifically the base64-encoded content from the GitHub API). Problem is I'm getting ASCII-encoded characters back (like `â¢` instead of `™`). How can I properly handle the incoming base64-encoded stream so that it's decoded as utf-8?

Comment: The MDN page you linked has a paragraph starting with the phrase "For use with Unicode or UTF-8 strings,".

Comment: Are you on node? There are better solutions than `atob`

Answer (score 530, accepted):

### The Unicode Problem

Though JavaScript (ECMAScript) has matured, the fragility of Base64, ASCII, and Unicode encoding has caused a lot of headaches (much of it is in this question's history).

Consider the following example:

```
const ok = "a";
console.log(ok.codePointAt(0).toString(16)); //   61: occupies < 1 byte

const notOK = "✓"
console.log(notOK.codePointAt(0).toString(16)); // 2713: occupies > 1 byte

console.log(btoa(ok));    // YQ==
console.log(btoa(notOK)); // error
```

Why do we encounter this?

> Base64, by design, expects binary data as its input. In terms of JavaScript strings, this means strings in which each character occupies only one byte. So if you pass a string into btoa() containing characters that occupy more than one byte, you will get an error, because this is not considered binary data.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa#unicode_strings) (2021)

The original MDN article also covered the broken nature of `window.btoa` and `.atob`, which have since been mended in modern ECMAScript. The original, now-dead MDN article explained:

> The "Unicode Problem"
> Since [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString)s are 16-bit-encoded strings, in most browsers calling `window.btoa` on a UTF-8 string will cause a `Character Out Of Range exception` if a character exceeds the range of a 8-bit byte (0x00~0xFF).

---

### Solution with binary interoperability

> *If you're not sure which solution you want, this is probably the one you want. Keep scrolling for the ASCII base64 solution and history of this answer.*
>
> ---
>
> You may also be interested in some of the answers that use `TextDecoder` like https://stackoverflow.com/a/77383580/1214800

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa#unicode_strings) (2021)

The solution recommended by MDN is to actually encode to and from a binary string representation:

#### Encoding UTF-8 ⇢ binary

```
// convert a UTF-8 string to a string in which
// each 16-bit unit occupies only one byte
function toBinary(string) {
  const codeUnits = new Uint16Array(string.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < codeUnits.length; i++) {
    codeUnits[i] = string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(codeUnits.buffer)));
}

// a string that contains characters occupying > 1 byte
let encoded = toBinary("✓ à la mode") // "EycgAOAAIABsAGEAIABtAG8AZABlAA=="
```

#### Decoding binary ⇢ UTF-8

```
function fromBinary(encoded) {
  const binary = atob(encoded);
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(binary.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return String.fromCharCode(...new Uint16Array(bytes.buffer));
}

// our previous Base64-encoded string
let decoded = fromBinary(encoded) // "✓ à la mode"
```

Where this fails a little, is that you'll notice the encoded string `EycgAOAAIABsAGEAIABtAG8AZABlAA==` no longer matches the previous solution's string `4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU=`. This is because it is a binary-encoded native JavaScript string, not a UTF8-encoded string. If this doesn't matter to you (i.e., you aren't converting strings represented in Unicode from another system or are fine with JavaScript's native UTF-16LE encoding), then you're good to go. If, however, you want to preserve the UTF-8 functionality, you're better off using the solution described below.

---

### Solution with ASCII base64 interoperability

*The entire history of this question shows just how many different ways we've had to work around broken encoding systems over the years. Though the original MDN article no longer exists, this solution is still arguably a better one, and does a great job of solving "The Unicode Problem" while maintaining plain text base64 strings that you can decode on, say, [base64decode.org](https://www.base64decode.org).*

There are two possible methods to solve this problem:

> - the first one is to escape the whole string (see [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)) and then encode it;
> - the second one is to convert the UTF-16 [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) to an unsigned 8-bit integer array (`Uint8Array`) of characters and then encode it.

*A note on previous solutions: the MDN article originally suggested using `unescape` and `escape` to solve the `Character Out Of Range` exception problem, but they have since been deprecated. Some other answers here have suggested working around this with `decodeURIComponent` and `encodeURIComponent`, this has proven to be unreliable and unpredictable. The most recent update to this answer uses modern JavaScript functions to improve speed and modernize code.*

*If you're trying to save yourself some time, you could also consider using a library:*

- [js-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64) (NPM, great for Node.js)
- [base64-js](https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js)

#### Encoding UTF-8 ⇢ base64

```
function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    // first we use encodeURIComponent to get percent-encoded Unicode,
    // then we convert the percent encodings into raw bytes which
    // can be fed into btoa.
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
        function toSolidBytes(match, p1) {
            return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
    }));
}

b64EncodeUnicode('✓ à la mode'); // "4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU="
b64EncodeUnicode('\n'); // "Cg=="
```

#### Decoding base64 ⇢ UTF-8

```
function b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
    // Going backwards: from bytestream, to percent-encoding, to original string.
    return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));
}

b64DecodeUnicode('4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU='); // "✓ à la mode"
b64DecodeUnicode('Cg=='); // "\n"
```

(Why do we need to do this? `('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2)` prepends a 0 to single character strings, for example, when `c == \n`, the `c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)` returns `a`, forcing `a` to be represented as `0a`).

---

#### TypeScript support

Here's the same solution with some additional TypeScript compatibility (via @MA-Maddin):

```
// Encoding UTF-8 ⇢ base64

function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(match, p1) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(p1, 16))
    }))
}

// Decoding base64 ⇢ UTF-8

function b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(Array.prototype.map.call(atob(str), function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2)
    }).join(''))
}
```

---

#### The first solution (deprecated)

This used `escape` and `unescape` (which are now deprecated, though this still works in all modern browsers):

```
function utf8_to_b64( str ) {
    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( str )));
}

function b64_to_utf8( str ) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob( str )));
}

// Usage:
utf8_to_b64('✓ à la mode'); // "4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU="
b64_to_utf8('4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU='); // "✓ à la mode"
```

---

And one last thing: I first encountered this problem when calling the GitHub API. To get this to work on (Mobile) Safari properly, I actually had to strip all white space from the base64 source *before* I could even decode the source. Whether or not this is still relevant in 2021, I don't know:

```
function b64_to_utf8( str ) {
    str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');    
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob( str )));
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp "The unescape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. Use decodeURI() or decodeURIComponent() instead."

Comment: **Update:** Solution #1 in MDN's [The "Unicode Problem"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#The_Unicode_Problem) was fixed, `b64DecodeUnicode('4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU=');` now correctly output "✓ à la mode"

Comment: Another way to decode would be `decodeURIComponent(atob('4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU=').split('').map(x => '%' + x.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).join(''))`

Not the most performant code, but it is what it is.

Comment: `return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(p1, 16));` to have TypeScript compatibility.

Comment: I have same issue can you please check it

https://jsfiddle.net/parthjasani/hz5713b0/2/

Comment: It seems the MDN article has been updated and the explanation has now been moved here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa#Unicode_strings

Comment: Why does this line first prepend '00' and then picks the last two chars?
  '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2)
Why doesn't it simply do this?
  '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)

Comment: @brandonscript appending '00' and slicing was a bit confusing (for me and @Milad), so I added a comment about that on answer. can you take a look at it?

Comment: Yeah I’m not sure either. And this keeps getting changed by ECMAScript and Mozilla, so the answer keeps changing. I don’t even see this solution in the link anymore. I’ll look at modernizing this answer since it’s such a high-traffic result.

Comment: Thank you @yaya, I didn’t realize it was left padding! I wish IE supported str.padStart(2, '0'). Question: would the solution be functionally equivalent with that?

Comment: @Milad I think they are same. the only difference is that `.slice(-2)` makes sure that max length is 2 (for example it converts `35f` to `5f`), but `.padStart(2, '0')` doesn't. but I think all utf-8 encoded characters are less than `ff`, otherwise, this solution wasn't totally correct. but to make sure it doesn't throw an error for unsupported outranged characters (if there are any), it's safer to not change it.

Comment: @yaya in theory, even if the original characters occupied more than 1 byte (e.g., 'à'), when translated to base64 they become 1-byte character sequences (since base64 produces ascii chars), so it should never be longer than 2 characters - for example:
'à' -[base64]-> 'w6A=' -[atob]-> 'Ã ' -[%encoding]-> '%c3%a0' -[decodeURIComponent]-> 'à'

Comment: @brandonscript thanks, but honestly i don't like the edit at all. previously there was a straightforward encode and decode function (2018-2021), but the 2021 solution doesn't have it, and it seems detailed and so long for busy developers. (I didn't understand it also.).

Comment: @yaya I hate it too, tbh. The trouble is that the information provided was conflicting with MDN, and there are some reasonably good reasons why. I will continue to monitor the sentiment of this answer and update it to make sure it's as helpful as possible. I did just make some minor changes to improve the heading, and hopefully explain better why there are two answers now.

Comment: @brandonscript thanks. i read it again and i get it know. the confusing part for me is that the first block of code doesn't contain the solution, and the first block of description also doesn't contain the solution. so maybe you can format it like : 1. (code description) first convert it to binary, then decode it. 2. code solution, the btoa(fromBinary(...)) code. 3. describing the problem and the code that describes the problem. or something like this. (it's just a suggestion, please don't apply it if you don't like it.)

Comment: See what you think now. Good ideas.

Comment: @brandonscript Sorry for the late reply. (it's your post, so when you don't mention me with @, I don't get any notifications.). I think that's well-formatted now. the only problem is that `Encoding UTF8 ⇢ binary` part doesn't contain the usage code (`let encoded = btoa(toBinary("✓ à la mode"))`).

Comment: @brandonscript and also maybe changing `btoa(toBinary("✓"))` to a single function Is more cool, like : `binaryEncode("✓")`. (just like base64 version)

Comment: @Brandonscript thanks, now the only concern is the function name. I'm not sure but shouldn't it be like : `b64BinaryEncode`? (since you combined the toBinary and btoa). I'm not sure about it however.

Comment: For 4 byte Unitcode character support you can use `Uint32Array` and `from/toCodePoint` instead of `Uint16Array` and `from/toCharCodeAt`. Also note that in some browsers there's a limit to the number of arguments you can pass to `String.fromCodePoint` so might not work for very long strings.

Comment: The headings "Encoding UTF8 ⇢ binary" and "Decoding binary ⇢ UTF-8" under "binary interoperability" are incorrect. The first of these takes a UTF-16 string (Javascript's native representation), encodes that string as individual UTF-16 code units, takes the binary representation of these code units, encodes each byte as an individual character in a binary string, and converts this binary string to base64 using btoa(). The second example does the reverse. At no point is UTF-8 involved. I corrected this in an edit but it has been reverted by the original author (improperly, I believe).

Comment: Indeed, it should be easy enough to confirm that the so-called "UTF-8 ⇢ binary" conversion above is actually a UTF-16 to binary conversion by entering the supplied input text "✓ à la mode" into base64encode.org and choosing UTF-16LE as the destination character set. The output will be the same as for the mislabeled example. Likewise, typing "EycgAOAAIABsAGEAIABtAG8AZABlAA==" into base64decode.org and choosing UTF-16LE as the source character set will give back the original string. Therefore, the first example's base64 output is actually a binary encoding of a UTF-16LE string, not UTF-8.

Comment: As further confirmation, please compare the results produced by the Javascript examples above with a couple of examples in Python: `base64.b64encode('✓ à la mode'.encode('utf-8'))` will produce the base64 string `'4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU='`, while `base64.b64encode('✓ à la mode'.encode('utf-16le'))` will produce the base64 string '`EycgAOAAIABsAGEAIABtAG8AZABlAA=='`.

Comment: @AdrianLopez Doesn't that mean that the code encodes UTF-8? Both base64encode.org and Python agree that `'✓ à la mode'` base64 encoded with UTF-8 is `'4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU='`. That's what OP's code outputs too.

Comment: @brandonscript, thank you for explaining your rationale. I won't attempt any further edits, but what I'm trying to get across here is that JavaScript strings are UTF-16 to begin with, which is why calling `charCodeAt()` on the characters in the string will give you a series of UTF-16 code units (one for each character) which the `toBinary()` function then converts to a binary string (still in UTF-16). In reverse, it's also why `fromBinary()` needs to reinterpret the `Uint8Array` as an`Uint16Array` before calling `fromCharCode()`, because the values are UTF-16 each split into two bytes.

Comment: @brandonscript, A key observation is the fact that Base64 deals with arbitrary 8-bit values while JavaScript deals with 16-bit code units. You can split a UTF-16 string into 8-bit bytes and encode that as Base64, but it's still a UTF-16 string. To produce something in JavaScript like what you're getting from GitHub you must first convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 and only then encode the resulting 8-bit code units as Base64. So, for encoding, it's UTF-16 to UTF-8 to Base64, while for decoding it's Base64 to UTF-8 to UTF-16. I've made an attempt to explain this in my own answer to your question.

Comment: @MichaelM. the function `b64EncodeUnicode()` does indeed encode UTF-8 into Base64. What I'm getting at is that the function `toBinary()` that appears above it encodes UTF-16 into Base64. The string '`✓ à la mode`' Base64 encoded with UTF-16LE is `EycgAOAAIABsAGEAIABtAG8AZABlAA==`, same as what the OP's `toBinary()` function outputs.

Comment: @AdrianLopez great! That works much better as an answer, upvoted. I'm going to delete my thread of comments here to keep this clean, might be worth it for you to do the same for anything that is already captured in your answer.

Answer (score 40):

Decoding base64 to UTF8 String

Below is current most voted answer by @brandonscript

```
function b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
    // Going backwards: from bytestream, to percent-encoding, to original string.
    return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));
}
```

Above code can work, but it's very slow. If your input is a very large base64 string, for example 30,000 chars for a base64 html document. It will need lots of computation.

Here is my answer, use built-in TextDecoder, nearly 10x faster than above code for large input.

```
function decodeBase64(base64) {
    const text = atob(base64);
    const length = text.length;
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(length);
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = text.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const decoder = new TextDecoder(); // default is utf-8
    return decoder.decode(bytes);
}
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty cool solution. I think it wouldn't have worked in the past, because atob and btoa were broken, but now they're not.

Comment: This is also about 7x faster than the one-liner from the other answer: `new TextDecoder().decode(Uint8Array.from(atob(b64), c => c.charCodeAt(0)))`

Comment: Thank you this solution also works with ```atob``` from ```react-native-quick-base64```

Answer (score 37):

Things change. The [escape/unescape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) methods have been deprecated.

You can URI encode the string before you Base64-encode it. Note that this does't produce Base64-encoded UTF8, but rather Base64-encoded URL-encoded data. Both sides must agree on the same encoding.

See working example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZgbPW

```
// encode string
var base64 = window.btoa(encodeURIComponent('€ 你好 æøåÆØÅ'));
// decode string
var str = decodeURIComponent(window.atob(tmp));
// str is now === '€ 你好 æøåÆØÅ'
```

For OP's problem a third party library such as [js-base64](https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64) should solve the problem.

Comment: I'd like to point out that you're not producing the base64 of the input string, but of his encoded component. So if you send it away the other party cannot decode it as "base64" and get the original string

Comment: You are correct, I have updated the text to point that out. Thanks. The alternative seems to be implementing base64 yourself, using a third party library (such as js-base64) or receiving "Error: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range."

Answer (score 25):

The complete article that works for me: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

The part where we encode from Unicode/UTF-8 is

```
function utf8_to_b64( str ) {
   return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( str )));
}

function b64_to_utf8( str ) {
   return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob( str )));
}

// Usage:
utf8_to_b64('✓ à la mode'); // "4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU="
b64_to_utf8('4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU='); // "✓ à la mode"
```

This is one of the most used methods nowadays.

Comment: Works for me as I am trying to decode Github API response which contains German umlaut. Thank you!!

Comment: unescape seems about to become deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/unescape

Answer (score 23):

If treating strings as bytes is more your thing, you can use the following functions

```
function u_atob(ascii) {
    return Uint8Array.from(atob(ascii), c => c.charCodeAt(0));
}

function u_btoa(buffer) {
    var binary = [];
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    for (var i = 0, il = bytes.byteLength; i < il; i++) {
        binary.push(String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]));
    }
    return btoa(binary.join(''));
}


// example, it works also with astral plane characters such as ''
var encodedString = new TextEncoder().encode('✓');
var base64String = u_btoa(encodedString);
console.log('✓' === new TextDecoder().decode(u_atob(base64String)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was crucial in helping me get this working, which took me many hours over multiple days. +1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51814273/470749

Comment: For a much faster and more cross-browser solution (but essentially the same output), please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53433503/5601591

Comment: u_atob and u_btoa use functions available in every browser since IE10 (2012), looks solid to me (if you refer to TextEncoder, that's just an example)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. My base64 encoded UTF-8 strings come from a Python script (`base64.b64encode`) and this makes it work with UTF-8 characters without changing anything on the Python side. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

Here is 2018 updated solution as described in the [Mozilla Development Resources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

**TO ENCODE FROM UNICODE TO B64**

```
function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    // first we use encodeURIComponent to get percent-encoded UTF-8,
    // then we convert the percent encodings into raw bytes which
    // can be fed into btoa.
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
        function toSolidBytes(match, p1) {
            return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
    }));
}

b64EncodeUnicode('✓ à la mode'); // "4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU="
b64EncodeUnicode('\n'); // "Cg=="
```

**TO DECODE FROM B64 TO UNICODE**

```
function b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
    // Going backwards: from bytestream, to percent-encoding, to original string.
    return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));
}

b64DecodeUnicode('4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU='); // "✓ à la mode"
b64DecodeUnicode('Cg=='); // "\n"
```

Comment: if i use b64EncodeUnicode(str) function in Javascript. How to Decode it in PHP? 
Can you convert function b64DecodeUnicode(str) to PHP function ?

Answer (score 6):

I would assume that one might want a solution that produces a widely useable base64 URI. Please visit `data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64,4pi44pi54pi64pi74pi84pi+4pi/` to see a demonstration (copy the data uri, open a new tab, paste the data URI into the address bar, then press enter to go to the page). Despite the fact that this URI is base64-encoded, the browser is still able to recognize the high code points and decode them properly. The minified encoder+decoder is 1058 bytes (+Gzip→589 bytes)

```
!function(e){"use strict";function h(b){var a=b.charCodeAt(0);if(55296<=a&&56319>=a)if(b=b.charCodeAt(1),b===b&&56320<=b&&57343>=b){if(a=1024*(a-55296)+b-56320+65536,65535<a)return d(240|a>>>18,128|a>>>12&63,128|a>>>6&63,128|a&63)}else return d(239,191,189);return 127>=a?inputString:2047>=a?d(192|a>>>6,128|a&63):d(224|a>>>12,128|a>>>6&63,128|a&63)}function k(b){var a=b.charCodeAt(0)<<24,f=l(~a),c=0,e=b.length,g="";if(5>f&&e>=f){a=a<<f>>>24+f;for(c=1;c<f;++c)a=a<<6|b.charCodeAt(c)&63;65535>=a?g+=d(a):1114111>=a?(a-=65536,g+=d((a>>10)+55296,(a&1023)+56320)):c=0}for(;c<e;++c)g+="\ufffd";return g}var m=Math.log,n=Math.LN2,l=Math.clz32||function(b){return 31-m(b>>>0)/n|0},d=String.fromCharCode,p=atob,q=btoa;e.btoaUTF8=function(b,a){return q((a?"\u00ef\u00bb\u00bf":"")+b.replace(/[\x80-\uD7ff\uDC00-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]?/g,h))};e.atobUTF8=function(b,a){a||"\u00ef\u00bb\u00bf"!==b.substring(0,3)||(b=b.substring(3));return p(b).replace(/[\xc0-\xff][\x80-\xbf]*/g,k)}}(""+void 0==typeof global?""+void 0==typeof self?this:self:global)
```

Below is the source code used to generate it.

```
var fromCharCode = String.fromCharCode;
var btoaUTF8 = (function(btoa, replacer){"use strict";
    return function(inputString, BOMit){
        return btoa((BOMit ? "\xEF\xBB\xBF" : "") + inputString.replace(
            /[\x80-\uD7ff\uDC00-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]?/g, replacer
        ));
    }
})(btoa, function(nonAsciiChars){"use strict";
    // make the UTF string into a binary UTF-8 encoded string
    var point = nonAsciiChars.charCodeAt(0);
    if (point >= 0xD800 && point <= 0xDBFF) {
        var nextcode = nonAsciiChars.charCodeAt(1);
        if (nextcode !== nextcode) // NaN because string is 1 code point long
            return fromCharCode(0xef/*11101111*/, 0xbf/*10111111*/, 0xbd/*10111101*/);
        // https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding#surrogate-formulae
        if (nextcode >= 0xDC00 && nextcode <= 0xDFFF) {
            point = (point - 0xD800) * 0x400 + nextcode - 0xDC00 + 0x10000;
            if (point > 0xffff)
                return fromCharCode(
                    (0x1e/*0b11110*/<<3) | (point>>>18),
                    (0x2/*0b10*/<<6) | ((point>>>12)&0x3f/*0b00111111*/),
                    (0x2/*0b10*/<<6) | ((point>>>6)&0x3f/*0b00111111*/),
                    (0x2/*0b10*/<<6) | (point&0x3f/*0b00111111*/)
                );
        } else return fromCharCode(0xef, 0xbf, 0xbd);
    }
    if (point <= 0x007f) return nonAsciiChars;
    else if (point <= 0x07ff) {
        return fromCharCode((0x6<<5)|(point>>>6), (0x2<<6)|(point&0x3f));
    } else return fromCharCode(
        (0xe/*0b1110*/<<4) | (point>>>12),
        (0x2/*0b10*/<<6) | ((point>>>6)&0x3f/*0b00111111*/),
        (0x2/*0b10*/<<6) | (point&0x3f/*0b00111111*/)
    );
});
```

Then, to decode the base64 data, either HTTP get the data as a data URI or use the function below.

```
var clz32 = Math.clz32 || (function(log, LN2){"use strict";
    return function(x) {return 31 - log(x >>> 0) / LN2 | 0};
})(Math.log, Math.LN2);
var fromCharCode = String.fromCharCode;
var atobUTF8 = (function(atob, replacer){"use strict";
    return function(inputString, keepBOM){
        inputString = atob(inputString);
        if (!keepBOM && inputString.substring(0,3) === "\xEF\xBB\xBF")
            inputString = inputString.substring(3); // eradicate UTF-8 BOM
        // 0xc0 => 0b11000000; 0xff => 0b11111111; 0xc0-0xff => 0b11xxxxxx
        // 0x80 => 0b10000000; 0xbf => 0b10111111; 0x80-0xbf => 0b10xxxxxx
        return inputString.replace(/[\xc0-\xff][\x80-\xbf]*/g, replacer);
    }
})(atob, function(encoded){"use strict";
    var codePoint = encoded.charCodeAt(0) << 24;
    var leadingOnes = clz32(~codePoint);
    var endPos = 0, stringLen = encoded.length;
    var result = "";
    if (leadingOnes < 5 && stringLen >= leadingOnes) {
        codePoint = (codePoint<<leadingOnes)>>>(24+leadingOnes);
        for (endPos = 1; endPos < leadingOnes; ++endPos)
            codePoint = (codePoint<<6) | (encoded.charCodeAt(endPos)&0x3f/*0b00111111*/);
        if (codePoint <= 0xFFFF) { // BMP code point
          result += fromCharCode(codePoint);
        } else if (codePoint <= 0x10FFFF) {
          // https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding#surrogate-formulae
          codePoint -= 0x10000;
          result += fromCharCode(
            (codePoint >> 10) + 0xD800,  // highSurrogate
            (codePoint & 0x3ff) + 0xDC00 // lowSurrogate
          );
        } else endPos = 0; // to fill it in with INVALIDs
    }
    for (; endPos < stringLen; ++endPos) result += "\ufffd"; // replacement character
    return result;
});
```

The advantage of being more standard is that this encoder and this decoder are more widely applicable because they can be used as a valid URL that displays correctly. Observe.

```js
(function(window){
    "use strict";
    var sourceEle = document.getElementById("source");
    var urlBarEle = document.getElementById("urlBar");
    var mainFrameEle = document.getElementById("mainframe");
    var gotoButton = document.getElementById("gotoButton");
    var parseInt = window.parseInt;
    var fromCodePoint = String.fromCodePoint;
    var parse = JSON.parse;
    
    function unescape(str){
        return str.replace(/\\u[\da-f]{0,4}|\\x[\da-f]{0,2}|\\u{[^}]*}|\\[bfnrtv"'\\]|\\0[0-7]{1,3}|\\\d{1,3}/g, function(match){
          try{
            if (match.startsWith("\\u{"))
              return fromCodePoint(parseInt(match.slice(2,-1),16));
            if (match.startsWith("\\u") || match.startsWith("\\x"))
              return fromCodePoint(parseInt(match.substring(2),16));
            if (match.startsWith("\\0") && match.length > 2)
              return fromCodePoint(parseInt(match.substring(2),8));
            if (/^\\\d/.test(match)) return fromCodePoint(+match.slice(1));
          }catch(e){return "\ufffd".repeat(match.length)}
          return parse('"' + match + '"');
        });
    }
    
    function whenChange(){
      try{ urlBarEle.value = "data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8;base64," + btoaUTF8(unescape(sourceEle.value), true);
      } finally{ gotoURL(); }
    }
    sourceEle.addEventListener("change",whenChange,{passive:1});
    sourceEle.addEventListener("input",whenChange,{passive:1});
    
    // IFrame Setup:
    function gotoURL(){mainFrameEle.src = urlBarEle.value}
    gotoButton.addEventListener("click", gotoURL, {passive: 1});
    function urlChanged(){urlBarEle.value = mainFrameEle.src}
    mainFrameEle.addEventListener("load", urlChanged, {passive: 1});
    urlBarEle.addEventListener("keypress", function(evt){
      if (evt.key === "enter") evt.preventDefault(), urlChanged();
    }, {passive: 1});
    
        
    var fromCharCode = String.fromCharCode;
    var btoaUTF8 = (function(btoa, replacer){
      "use strict";
        return function(inputString, BOMit){
         return btoa((BOMit?"\xEF\xBB\xBF":"") + inputString.replace(
          /[\x80-\uD7ff\uDC00-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]?/g, replacer
      ));
     }
    })(btoa, function(nonAsciiChars){
  "use strict";
     // make the UTF string into a binary UTF-8 encoded string
     var point = nonAsciiChars.charCodeAt(0);
     if (point >= 0xD800 && point <= 0xDBFF) {
      var nextcode = nonAsciiChars.charCodeAt(1);
      if (nextcode !== nextcode) { // NaN because string is 1code point long
       return fromCharCode(0xef/*11101111*/, 0xbf/*10111111*/, 0xbd/*10111101*/);
      }
      // https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding#surrogate-formulae
      if (nextcode >= 0xDC00 && nextcode <= 0xDFFF) {
       point = (point - 0xD800) * 0x400 + nextcode - 0xDC00 + 0x10000;
       if (point > 0xffff) {
        return fromCharCode(
         (0x1e/*0b11110*/<<3) | (point>>>18),
         (0x2/*0b10*/<<6) | ((point>>>12)&0x3f/*0b00111111*/),
         (0x2/*0b10*/<<6) | ((point>>>6)&0x3f/*0b00111111*/),
         (0x2/*0b10*/<<6) | (point&0x3f/*0b00111111*/)
        );
       }
      } else {
       return fromCharCode(0xef, 0xbf, 0xbd);
      }
     }
     if (point <= 0x007f) { return inputString; }
     else if (point <= 0x07ff) {
      return fromCharCode((0x6<<5)|(point>>>6), (0x2<<6)|(point&0x3f/*00111111*/));
     } else {
      return fromCharCode(
       (0xe/*0b1110*/<<4) | (point>>>12),
       (0x2/*0b10*/<<6) | ((point>>>6)&0x3f/*0b00111111*/),
       (0x2/*0b10*/<<6) | (point&0x3f/*0b00111111*/)
      );
     }
    });
    setTimeout(whenChange, 0);
})(window);
```

```css
img:active{opacity:0.8}
```

```html
<center>
<textarea id="source" style="width:66.7vw">Hello \u1234 W\186\0256ld!
Enter text into the top box. Then the URL will update automatically.
</textarea><br />
<div style="width:66.7vw;display:inline-block;height:calc(25vw + 1em + 6px);border:2px solid;text-align:left;line-height:1em">
<input id="urlBar" style="width:calc(100% - 1em - 13px)" /><img id="gotoButton" src="data:image/png;base64,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" style="width:calc(1em + 4px);line-height:1em;vertical-align:-40%;cursor:pointer" />
<iframe id="mainframe" style="width:66.7vw;height:25vw" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</center>
```

In addition to being very standardized, the above code snippets are also very fast. Instead of an indirect chain of succession where the data has to be converted several times between various forms (such as in Riccardo Galli's response), the above code snippet is as direct as performantly possible. It uses only one simple fast `String.prototype.replace` call to process the data when encoding, and only one to decode the data when decoding. Another plus is that (especially for big strings), `String.prototype.replace` allows the browser to automatically handle the underlying memory management of resizing the string, leading a significant performance boost especially in evergreen browsers like Chrome and Firefox that heavily optimize `String.prototype.replace`. Finally, the icing on the cake is that for you latin script exclūsīvō users, strings which don't contain any code points above 0x7f are extra fast to process because the string remains unmodified by the replacement algorithm.

I have created a github repository for this solution at https://github.com/anonyco/BestBase64EncoderDecoder/

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "user-created way" vs. "interpretable by the browser"? What is the value-add of using this solution over, say, what Mozilla recommends?

Comment: @brandonscript Mozilla is different from MDN. MDN is user-created content. The page on MDN that recommends your solution was user-created content, not browser vendor created content.

Comment: Is your solution vendor created? I’d so, I’d suggest giving credit to the origin. If not, then it is also user-created, and no different than MDN’s answer?

Comment: @brandonscript Good point. You are correct. I removed that piece of text. Also, check out the demo I added.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR one-liner solution:

```js
const base64Decode = base64EncodedString =>
  new TextDecoder().decode(Uint8Array.from(atob(base64EncodedString), m => m.codePointAt(0)));

const decodedString = base64Decode('R8O8bnRlciBNw7hsbGVyIFPDoW5jaGV6IFBlw7FhIPCfjokK');
console.log(decodedString); // Günter Møller Sánchez Peña
```

Comment: This is a really slick way of tackling this. Great job!

Answer (score 3):

If trying to decode a Base64 representation of utf8 encoded data *in node*, you can use the native [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) helper

```js
Buffer.from("4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU=", "base64").toString(); // '✓ à la mode'
```

The `toString` method of Buffer defaults to utf8, but you can specify any desired encoding. For example, the reverse operation would look like this

```js
Buffer.from('✓ à la mode', "utf8").toString("base64"); // "4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU="
```

Comment: Buffer is a part of Node.js. Question is about JavaScript in general

Answer (score 2):

This is my one-liner solution combining [Jackie Hans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64752311/1285585) and [some code from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72365339/1285585):

```js
const utf8_encoded_text = new TextDecoder().decode(Uint8Array.from(window.atob(base_64_decoded_text).split("").map(x => x.charCodeAt(0))));
```

Answer (score 1):

## The Binary String Concept

A problem with the functions `btoa()` and `atob()` is that they both operate on `string` values but the contents of these strings are different from what strings are normally expected to contain. Strings received by `btoa()`, for instance, are expected to be formatted as *binary strings*, which are array-like sequences in which each 16-bit character represents an 8-bit value. Every element in the string is expected to contain a value between 0 - 255, and character values outside that range are considered invalid. Values returned by `atob()` are formatted the same way. It would make more sense if these functions worked with byte arrays instead, but they both use strings.

Unicode strings in Javascript, by contrast, are stored as a series of UTF-16 code units where each code unit has a value between 0 - 65,535. Passing a Unicode string to `btoa()` will work correctly if the characters contained in the string all lie in the Latin1 range (0 - 255), but the call will fail otherwise. Its counterpart `atob()`, on the other hand, will take a Base64 formatted string and return a binary string without any regard to whether the contents represent a Latin1 string, a UTF-8 string, a UTF-16 string, or arbitrary binary data. This is by design.

Applying this to the specific example presented in the question, consider the UTF-8 and UTF-16 representations of the Unicode "Trade Mark Sign" character, ™. That character's UTF-8 representation is `0xE2` `0x84` `0xA2`. The Base64 representation of this sequence is `'4oSi'`. Feeding `'4oSi'` to `atob()` will return a string consisting of three 16-bit values each representing one byte: `0x00E2`, `0x0084`, and `0x00A2`. Interpreted as a binary string these values represent the UTF-8 sequence `0xE2`, `0x84`, `0xA2` (the original ™ character, as expected). Interpreted as an ordinary UTF-16 string, however, the sequence represents the string `'â\x84¢'`, which is what you're getting.

## Encoding and Decoding Native Strings

### Binary Encoding

Before we can convert a Unicode string to Base64 we need to decide on a binary encoding for that string. This can be UTF-8, UTF-16, or any other encoding that's able to represent the original string. We can write some functions to convert from native strings to binary strings for particular encodings:

#### Native String to UTF-8

```
function encodeAsUTF8(str) {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();

    const utf8 = encoder.encode(str);

    var binaryString = '';
    for (let b = 0; b < utf8.length; ++b) {
        binaryString += String.fromCharCode(utf8[b]);
    }

    return binaryString;
}
```

#### Native String to UTF-16

```
function encodeAsUTF16(str) {
    var utf16 = new Uint16Array(str.length);

    for (let p = 0; p < utf16.length; ++p) {
        utf16[p] = str.charCodeAt(p);
    }

    const bytes = new Uint8Array(utf16.buffer);

    var binaryString = '';
    for (let b = 0; b < bytes.length; ++b) {
        binaryString += String.fromCharCode(bytes[b]);
    }

    return binaryString;        
}
```

Other encodings are possible, but the two above should suffice to illustrate the concept.

### Decoding

Converting from a binary encoding to a native string requires knowing the source encoding so the binary values are correctly interpreted. Taking UTF-8 and UTF-16 as examples again, we can write functions to convert from UTF-8 and UTF-16 binary strings to native strings:

#### UTF-8 to Native String

```
function decodeUTF8(binary) {
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(binary.length);
    for (let b = 0; b < bytes.length; ++b) {
        bytes[b] = binary.charCodeAt(b);
    }

    const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

    return decoder.decode(bytes);
}
```

#### UTF-16 to Native String

```
function decodeUTF16(binary) {
    const utf16 = new Uint8Array(binary.length);
    for (let b = 0; b < utf16.length; ++b) {
        utf16[b] = binary.charCodeAt(b);
    }

    const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-16');

    return decoder.decode(utf16);
}
```

### Native String to Base64

With the various string encoding functions in place we can encode a string as UTF-8 and convert this in turn to Base64 by calling:

```
base64string = btoa(encodeAsUTF8('™'));
```

We can also encode a string as UTF-16 and convert this to Base64 by calling:

```
base64string = btoa(encodeAsUTF16('™'));
```

### Base64 to Native String

To convert a UTF-8 encoded string from Base64 to a native string, call:

```
decodeUTF8(atob(base64string));
```

To convert a UTF-16 encoded string from Base64 to a native string, call:

```
decodeUTF16(atob(base64string));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some future-proof code for browsers that may lack `escape/unescape()`. Note that IE 9 and older don't support `atob/btoa()`, so you'd need to use custom base64 functions for them.

```
// Polyfill for escape/unescape
if( !window.unescape ){
    window.unescape = function( s ){
        return s.replace( /%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function( m, p ) {
            return String.fromCharCode( '0x' + p );
        } );
    };
}
if( !window.escape ){
    window.escape = function( s ){
        var chr, hex, i = 0, l = s.length, out = '';
        for( ; i < l; i ++ ){
            chr = s.charAt( i );
            if( chr.search( /[A-Za-z0-9\@\*\_\+\-\.\/]/ ) > -1 ){
                out += chr; continue; }
            hex = s.charCodeAt( i ).toString( 16 );
            out += '%' + ( hex.length % 2 != 0 ? '0' : '' ) + hex;
        }
        return out;
    };
}

// Base64 encoding of UTF-8 strings
var utf8ToB64 = function( s ){
    return btoa( unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) ) );
};
var b64ToUtf8 = function( s ){
    return decodeURIComponent( escape( atob( s ) ) );
};
```

A more comprehensive example for UTF-8 encoding and decoding can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/47zwb41o/

Answer (score 0):

**2023**: There is still no built in support in browsers for encoding and decoding base64 to UTF8.

Unless you are really into reinventing the wheel and testing edge cases, for both browsers and Node use https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of base64 and binary, I perform the encoding into hex. It's not as good as base 64, but the payload is definitely smaller than binary in instances where it'll be interpreted as a string.

```js
function strToHex(str) {
  return Array.from(str).map(char =>
    char.codePointAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, '0')
  ).join('');
}

function hexToStr(hex) {
  let result = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 4) {
    result += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substring(i, i + 4), 16));
  }
  return result;
}

const hexed = strToHex("Łørem Ipsüм");
console.log(hexed);

const dehexed = hexToStr(hexed);
console.log(dehexed);
```

Answer (score -1):

Small correction, unescape and escape are deprecated, so:

```
function utf8_to_b64( str ) {
    return window.btoa(decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(str)));
}

function b64_to_utf8( str ) {
     return decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(window.atob(str)));
}


function b64_to_utf8( str ) {
    str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');    
    return decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(window.atob(str)));
}
```

Comment: Looks like the doc link is even different from this now, suggesting a regex solution to manage it.

Comment: This will not work, because `encodeURIComponent` is the inverse of `decodeURIComponent`, i.e. it will just undo the conversion. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31412163/1534459 for a great explanation of what is happening with `escape` and `unescape`.

Comment: @canaaerus I don't understand your comment? escape and unescape are deprecated, I just swap them with [decode|encode]URIComponent function :-)
Everything is work just fine. Read the question first

Comment: @Darkves: The reason why `encodeURIComponent` is used, is to correctly handle (the whole range of) unicode strings. So e.g. `window.btoa(decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('€')))` gives `Error: String contains an invalid character` because it’s the same as `window.btoa('€')` and `btoa` can not encode `€`.

Comment: No point in arguing this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxmRmj gives "Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range."

Comment: @Darkves: Yes, that's correct. But you can't swap escape with EncodeURIComponent and unescape with DecodeURIComponent, because the Encode and the escape methods don't do the same thing. Same with decode&unescape. I originally made the same mistake, btw.  You should notice that if you take a string,  UriEncode it, then UriDecode it, you get the same string back that you inputted. So doing that would be nonsense. When you unescape a string encoded with encodeURIComponent, you don't get the same string back that you inputted, so that's why with escape/unescape it works, but not with yours.

Comment: @Stefan Steiger look at Tedd Hansen comment.
I made a mistake, and I'm sry.
HF commenting around :)

Answer (score -1):

including above solution if still facing issue try as below, Considerign the case where escape is not supported for TS.

```
blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", csv_content]); // this will make symbols to appears in excel
```

for csv_content you can try like below.

```
function b64DecodeUnicode(str: any) {        
        return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map((c: any) => {
            return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }).join(''));
    }
```