# Gmail API encoding html and css in addition to base64

Tags: encoding, gmail, gmail-api

I'm pulling some mail from the Gmail API. I've got some sample body text here. This is after base-64 decoding. This is the body of a sample email from my inbox.

`Mobile Web Developer - new
Moovweb
http://www.glassdoor.com/partner/jobListing.htm?pos=101&ao=77320&s=224&guid=00000152113cfb4fa8f086376239205e&src=GD_JOB_AD&t=JA&extid=13&exst=O&ist=&ast=O&vt=e&ja=23120341&uido=50A7E22F0FAE3A77415539AAADB05038&slr=false&cb=1451988155901&jobListingId=1579397251&utm_medium=email&utm_source=jobalert&utm_campaign=jobAlertAlert&utm_content=ja-viewjob&encryptedUserId=50A7E22F0FAE3A77415539AAADB05038
Web Developer - new
Applied Systems
http://www.glassdoor.com/partner/jobListing.htmÃœÃLLâ€°Ëœ[ÃMÅ’Å½IÅ“ÃLÅ’ï¿¾  â„¢ÃZYLMLÅ’LLÃ˜Ã™Ëœï¿¾ËœNÅ’
Å’ÃÃÅ’Å’ÃŽLÅ’
YIÅ“ÃœËœÃQÃ‘Ã’â€œÃâ€”ÃQ ï¿¾Rï¿¾Iâ„¢^YLLÃ‰â„¢^ÃSÃ‰Å¡\ÃIËœ\ÃSÃ‰ï¿¾ï¿¾YIÅ¡ËœOLÅ’ÃŒLÅ’ÃIï¿¾ZYÃMLMÃ‘LÅ’â€˜Å’ï¿¾QLÃMÃÃMMLÃŽPPPQÅ’
LÃŽ Å“Ã›ï¿¾YËœ[Ã™IËœÃ˜ï¿¾LM
LNNMMNLÅ½IÅ¡â€ºÃ˜â€œ\Ã[â„¢Ã’YLMLN
LÅ½`

As you can see, after base-64 decoding it, part of it is decoded correctly, such as the title nad the url. The garbage bellow is the content that was originally html and css, I believe, so it makes sense that it would have been encoded differently on Google's side. Does anyone know what encoding this is?

I've tried:

```
        `mb_convert_encoding($body_string, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");`
```

and

```
        `mb_convert_encoding($body_string, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1");`
```

With no luck.

Comment: Did you request format=FULL or format=RAW on the message? Can you provide the MIME* and Content* headers from the email?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106476/using-javascripts-atob-to-decode-base64-doesnt-properly-decode-utf-8-strings) should solve it.

Comment: Try utf8_decode()