# base 64 encode and decode a string in angular (2+)

Tags: angular, typescript, npm-install

***How to encode or decode a string in angular 2 with base64 ???***
My front-end tool is Angular 2. I had a password string, before passing it to API I need to base64 encode. Since in service base64 encoded string will be decoded.

So I am looking for some base64 encode/decode library for Angular2/Typescript and some options.

Thanks!!!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Use the [`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) function to encode:

```js
console.log(btoa("password")); // cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

To decode, you can use the [`atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) function:

```js
console.log(atob("cGFzc3dvcmQ=")); // password
```

Comment: Before using this you may want to confirm if your target browsers support this: https://caniuse.com/#search=btoa

Comment: @edrian Should be OK as long as you're not supporting a very old version of IE.

Comment: how would I typecast a variable as base 64? Im using FileReader and getting base64 string as the result

Comment: @virtualLast Not sure what you mean. It's just a string, what do you want to cast it to?

Comment: I found an ImageData type and wondered if there was a Base64 Type or something similar, I've set it as string for now but wondered if there was something better

Comment: Just a word of caution that btoa() and atob() do not support utf-8 characters!

Comment: @darwin exactly, so how to with utf-8?

Comment: @Robert this should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106476/using-javascripts-atob-to-decode-base64-doesnt-properly-decode-utf-8-strings

Comment: Is there anyway to use this in html ?

Comment: @TheMuyu Yes, like you use any JavaScript in HTML.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen how ? can you explain ?

Comment: @TheMuyu [How to use JavaScript in HTML](https://www.google.com/search?&q=how+to+use+javascript+in+html).

Answer (score 26):

From Angular 12 `btoa()` and `atob()` functions are deprecated. Use these instead:

```
console.log(Buffer.from("Hello World").toString('base64'));
// SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=
console.log(Buffer.from("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=", 'base64').toString('binary'))
// Hello World
```

Note: you must explicit encoding!

Comment: getting `ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined`

Comment: I got this error too. After some research, I noticed that the deprecation warning of the btoa function says: "This function is only provided for compatibility with legacy web platform APIs and should never be used in new code, because they use strings to represent binary data and predate the introduction of typed arrays in JavaScript. For code running using Node.js APIs, converting between base64-encoded strings and binary data should be performed using Buffer.from(str, 'base64') andbuf.toString('base64')". So it may be used for APIs, not for client side code.

Comment: `ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined` error you can solve doing: installing Buffer, with npm i buffer and import it where you call the function
See [Convert a string to base64 in JavaScript. btoa and atob are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70733727/7757505)

Comment: Thoose deprecations are a false alert and cames from the nodeJS api, that is needed by angular tools but will not be present in browser context. You must use btoa/atob in browser platform an Buffer in server platform. Using window.atob instead of atob is a workaround to get rid of it. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45566

Answer (score 5):

For **encoding** to **base64** in **Angular2**, you can use **btoa()** function.

Example:-

```
console.log(btoa("stringAngular2")); 
// Output:- c3RyaW5nQW5ndWxhcjI=
```

For **decoding** from **base64** in **Angular2**, you can use **atob()** function.

Example:-

```
console.log(atob("c3RyaW5nQW5ndWxhcjI=")); 
// Output:- stringAngular2
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `btoa("yourstring")`

more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

TypeScript is a superset of Javascript, it can use existing Javascript libraries and web APIs

Answer (score 2):

Use `btoa()` for encode and `atob()` for decode

```
text_val:any="your encoding text";
```

Encoded Text: `console.log(btoa(this.text_val)); //eW91ciBlbmNvZGluZyB0ZXh0`

Decoded Text: `console.log(atob("eW91ciBlbmNvZGluZyB0ZXh0")); //your encoding text`

Comment: It's awesome that you want to help, but this answer doesn't add any extra value, since it is a copy of the accepted answer. On SO we like to avoid repetition. Please consider removing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more complete solution, you can use the turbocommons library. Just install it:

```
npm install turbocommons-ts
```

And then call the method you need:

```
import { ConversionUtils } from 'turbocommons-ts';

console.log(ConversionUtils.stringToBase64('hello'));
console.log(ConversionUtils.base64ToString('aGVsbG8='));
```

This library is open source and extensively tested. More info here:

https://turboframework.org/en/blog/2022-10-26/encode-decode-base64-strings-javascript-typescript-php