# Using Base64 encoding in Angular 4

Tags: angular, encoding, module, base64

I want to send the username and password to the server using Base64 encoding.

I found that I can import the following module using npm:

```
    npm install --save angular-base64
```

I have verified that following folder is created in my project foler: node_modules\angular-base64

In my component.js file I tried to use any of the following line to import the component:

```
    import 'angular-base64/angular-base64';
```

It does not complain about the importing but when I try to use following line:

```
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode('username:temppass'));
```

It says "**Can not find base64**".

Comment: if you do this because of security, you fail. When dealing with secrets use https (TLS, SSL a.s.o)

Comment: @stefanbachert still we need to send the password encrypted because the server side code requires it.

Comment: With the [angular-base64](https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64) library, be sure to prefix with a dollar-sign, `$`, i.e. `$base64.encode('username:temppass')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [base 64 encode and decode a string in angular (2+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972330/base-64-encode-and-decode-a-string-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You don't really need an external library for that purpose.

> The WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.btoa() method creates a base-64 encoded
>   ASCII string from a String object in which each character in the
>   string is treated as a byte of binary data.

Use the [`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) function to encode:

```js
console.log(btoa("username:temppass")); // dXNlcm5hbWU6dGVtcHBhc3M=
```

To decode, you can use the [`atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) function:

```js
console.log(atob("dXNlcm5hbWU6dGVtcHBhc3M=")); // username:temppass
```

See the list of supported browser [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=btoa)

Comment: btoa() can not be used to encode characters outside of the Latin1 range.

Comment: @Shadoweb `Buffer.from(<string>).toString('base64')` shall be used instead of `btoa()` now

Comment: Thanks @StephanKulla, but in the end it was only VSC complaining wrongly, and a restart solved the issue.