# How can I convert the URL of an image to base64 (IONIC3)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

```html
 getimage(Type){
        let options: CameraOptions;
        if (Type == 'camera') {
            options = {
                quality: 100,
                destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE

            };
        }
        else if (Type == 'gallery') {
            options = {
                sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
                destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE

            };

        }

        this.camera.getPicture(options).then((img) => {
            let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + img;
                this.test(base64Image ) 
})

test(input:string)
    {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: input,
            subTitle: input,
            buttons: ['OK']
        });
        alert.present();
```

the base64Image didn't output a base64image 
i compare the result of the output and the result of converting the same image enligne and the result of the output of my code is always the same with diffrent image

Comment: are the camera options set? if your Type is not 'gallery' or 'camera', the options are undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [base 64 encode and decode a string in angular (2+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972330/base-64-encode-and-decode-a-string-in-angular-2)