# Encoding in C# and Decoding in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, encoding, base64

I have encoded some text in C# like below:

```
var encodedCredential = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Sample text")));
```

The encoded String is :`IgBTAGEAbQBwAGwAZQAgAHQAZQB4AHQAIgA=`

I want to decode the encoded String in java script.

I have tried the below

```
decodeURIComponent(atob("IgBTAGEAbQBwAGwAZQAgAHQAZQB4AHQAIgA="))
decodeURIComponent(atob("IgBTAGEAbQBwAGwAZQAgAHQAZQB4AHQAIgA=").replace(' ',''))
```

[image]

The result is something different, There are some spaces in each letter. I cant even replace the spaces.

Comment: Just to be clear: base64 encoding/decoding is not encryption - there is no key involved, so anyone can "decrypt" this data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Javascript's atob to decode base64 doesn't properly decode utf-8 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106476/using-javascripts-atob-to-decode-base64-doesnt-properly-decode-utf-8-strings)

Comment: It is because you encoded a Unicode string.  Try encoding it as an ASCII string instead (or UTF-8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use UTF-8 encoding in C#. Export base64 by this command

```
Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Sample text"))
```

Answer (score 0):

@King_Fisher, you shouldn't be getting additional spaces, also the replace method will replace a single occurrence.

Here's what I did with your code (see attached screenshot)[image]