# how to convert array of json to base64 - php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a function that convert my inputs to base64 encode:

```
function goToMap()
{

 $rows = $('.address');
        $length_rows = $('.address').length;

        $arr_objs = Array();
        $rows.each( function(){

            $obj = {};
            $row_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

            $obj.id = $row_id;
            $obj.address  = $('#address_'+$row_id).val();
            $obj.type     = $('#type_'+$row_id).val();

            $obj.lat      = $(this).attr('data-lat')
            $obj.lnt      = $(this).attr('data-lnt');


            $arr_objs.push($obj);

        });

      $b4 = btoa($arr_objs);

      location.href = 'http:/****/?b4='+$b4;

}
```

but when I convert my inputs to base64 with `btoa` function, I can't convert it to pure `json` with `php`:

my base64 output:

```
W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3RdLFtvYmplY3QgT2JqZWN0XSxbb2JqZWN0IE9iamVjdF0=
```

after convert with php:

```
$all_address = json_decode(base64_decode($gets['b4']),true);
var_dump($all_address);
return;
```

output:

```
string(47) "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
```

my json output of my function:

```
[
  {
    "id": "35",
    "address": "تهران  خیابان امام خمینی",
    "type": "1",
    "lat": "35.6886846123666",
    "lnt": "51.387248933315284"
  },
  {
    "id": "91",
    "address": "تهران  خیابان امام خمینی",
    "type": "1",
    "lat": "",
    "lnt": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "36",
    "address": "کرج  کوچه جعفری",
    "type": "2",
    "lat": "35.84001878731047",
    "lnt": "50.93909069895744"
  }
]
```

Comment: You need to convert the json to a string with `JSON.stringify($arr_objs)` before converting it to base 64

Comment: @Jason Spradlin I got this message: InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character

Comment: Won't be able to troubleshoot that without seeing the actual object

Comment: @Jason Spradlin updated my quesiton and added output of json string.

Comment: I am able to run JSON.stringify() on that data

Comment: it's my code:     `$jsons = JSON.stringify($arr_objs);
      $b4 = btoa($jsons);`

Comment: I got this error from: `btoa` function.

Comment: yes, I see that now.  The issue is that `btoa` can only base-64 encode characters in the Latin1 set, and Arabic requires UTF-8.  You may want to URI-encode the full stringified content before base-64 encoding it, but if you do, you'll have to then decode that in the PHP as well

Comment: That is to say Obj -> JSON.stringify -> encodeURIComponent -> btoa --> to server --> un-base-64 -> un-uri-encode

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with this fucntion:

```
function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(match, p1) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(p1, 16))
    }))
}
```

[Using Javascript's atob to decode base64 doesn't properly decode utf-8 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106476/using-javascripts-atob-to-decode-base64-doesnt-properly-decode-utf-8-strings)