# Expo / React Native Basic Authorization

Tags: react-native, authorization, expo

I'm new to React native and Expo, but started to write my own app on it, with the same backend i used with my Cordova app.

Unfortunately i hit a roadblock trying to recreate the btoa() function from browsers, that i use to authenticate users with Basic authorization.

No matter what i try, i can't seem to get the same result as i did with btoa. I tried researching the subject, but i can't find a solid answer what's the difference between Base64.encode() and btoa().

I know i'm doing something wrong. When i try out the post request with Postman, i get the correct Basic auth token with it. But when i do it in code with base64 encoding(tried multiple libraries), the result differs. 
Example:

test@test.com:asdasd

in postman: "dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbTphc2Rhc2Rhc2Q="

in app(to utf8, then base64): "W29iamVjdCBBcnJheUJ1ZmZlcl0="

Relevant part of my code:

```
const utf8_enc = utf8.encode(email+':'+password);
const b64_enc = base64.encode(utf8_enc);
console.log(b64_enc);
```

Used libraries:

Base64- https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64

UTF8 - https://github.com/mathiasbynens/utf8.js

Please tell me why are the two different, and how can i recreate the Postman version.

Thank you!

Comment: Two questions, 1) Is that the correct string from postman? When I test my example code, I get `dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbTphc2Rhc2Q=` when using `btoa()`. 2) Why are you using `utf8.encode()` prior to `base64.encode()`? My understanding of `btoa` is that it's just a Base64 encoding of a string, so you only need `base64.encode()'.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I see what's happening now. If you follow the docs for that `utf8` package, it won't import correctly in React Native. You can see that it's not imported correctly by trying to access `decode()` or `version` as both will give you `undefined`. I think the reason is because they don't support es2015 modules ([see this rejected PR](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/utf8.js/pull/23)). This package will however work fine in Node.js or in the browser.

Oddly enough, you do have access to `encode()` when you import. It just doesn't do what you think it does. When you attempt to use `encode()`, all it actually returns is the string: `[object ArrayBuffer]`. In fact, no matter what string you pass to it, it'll always return the same result. Now if you use `btoa()` on this string (with or without UTF-8 conversion since there's no difference in this case), you will see that you get that same output in the browser: `W29iamVjdCBBcnJheUJ1ZmZlcl0=`

So, how to get around this?

If all you expect are extended ASCII strings, then you don't need to encode it in UTF-8 as they will all be within the valid character set. So you can just do:

```
 base64.encode(email+':'+password);
```

However, if you anticipate supporting all Unicode characters, then you have a few options to convert that string:

1. Fork the `utf8` package to have it support modules/exporting.
2. Copy paste the entirety of the `utf8` source and put it in your own local library and export the functions.
3. Write your own UTF-8 encoder/decoder using the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106476/using-javascripts-atob-to-decode-base64-doesnt-properly-decode-utf-8-strings) which itself is from [the MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding).

So there's a reference to *a* solution, here is the relevant encode part of the code from the MDN documentation turned into a function:

```
function utf8encode(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(
    match,
    p1
  ) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(p1, 16));
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm using utf-8, because that is what's written in the base64 documentation. Removing the utf8 conversion, gives the same result with this example. 

I actually found that answer, that's why i'm using base64, but it doesn't give the same result as btoa() in browsers, that's why i'm so confused.

Comment: @FerencDobó Ok, figured it out. I only looked at the simple example in their docs and just assumed UTF-8 would do something strange to plain ASCII strings. Very wrong about that, but your comment led me to figure out what was really going on. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your time put in. In the end i figured out that i passed the email and password incorrectly, rendering them into one object. But i figured this out, because you said you get the same results always, which i had as well, even without the utf-8 conversion.