# UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes C# in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I need help to try make this piece of code in javascript.
In c# is very simple however I don't know how I can do it in javascript.

Any help?
Thank you

```
string user = txtUser.Text;
byte[] userBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user);
user = Convert.ToBase64String(userBytes, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106476/using-javascripts-atob-to-decode-base64-doesnt-properly-decode-utf-8-strings

Comment: Take a look at the "btoa" function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Javascript's atob to decode base64 doesn't properly decode utf-8 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106476/using-javascripts-atob-to-decode-base64-doesnt-properly-decode-utf-8-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `btoa()` function in **JavaScript** to achieve the same functionality as **C#** code you mentioned as shown below

```
var user = document.getElementById("txtUser").value;
user = btoa(user);
```