# Python to javascript, js authentication

Tags: javascript, python, translate

I need help converting this piece of python to javascript.

```
auth = "Basic " + base64.b64encode(bytes(IdentityClientId + ":" + IdentityClientSecret, "utf-8")).decode('ascii')
```

What I've tried:

```
var auth = "Basic " + unescape(btoa(IdentityClientId + ":" + IdentityClientSecret));
```

No luck so far.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more what's your problem? What does not work here?

Comment: Basically just to convert the python to Javascript, the Javascript portion does not parse the same as the python one.

Comment: I'm not a python expert, but from what i tried, i get the same result for both version. I suspect the problem comes from encoding: in your login and password, are there any special chars that could mess it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected in the comment, you have some problem with Unicode characters.

You can use this to encode properly the characters:

```js
function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(match, p1) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(p1, 16));
    }));
}

console.log(b64EncodeUnicode('lögin:password'));
```

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30106476/5860648) for more details about this!