# JavaScript atob is different than Notepad++ Base64 Decode

Tags: javascript, base64

I am receiving the content of a zip file (from an API) as a Base64-encoded string.

If I paste that string into Notepad++ and go

> Plugins > MIME Tools > Base64 Decode

and save it as `test.zip`, it becomes a valid zip file, I can open it.

Now, I am trying to achieve the same thing **in JavaScript**.

I have tried `atob()`, and probably everything mentioned in [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106476/using-javascripts-atob-to-decode-base64-doesnt-properly-decode-utf-8-strings) and [the code from Mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding).

`atob` produces a similar content, but some characters are decoded differently (hence becomes an invalid zip file). The other methods throw an invalid URI error.

How can I reproduce Notepad++ behaviour in JavaScript?

Comment: How are you turning the output from `atob()` into a file?

Comment: @Phil This is what I used to save the file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file#30832210

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `window.atob` is only good for decoding data which fits in a UTF-8 string. Anything which cannot be represented in UTF-8 string will not be equal to its binary form when decoded. Javascript, at most, will try encoding the resultant bytes in to UTF-8 character sequence. This is the reason why your zip archive is rendered invalid eventually.

The moment you do the following:

```
var data = window.atob(encoded_data)
```

... you are having a different representation of your data in a UTF-8 string which is referenced by the variable `data`.

You should decode your binary data directly to an `ArrayBuffer`. And `window.atob` is not a good fit for this.

[Here](https://github.com/danguer/blog-examples/blob/master/js/base64-binary.js) is a function which can convert base64 encoded data directly in to an `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: Amazing! I spent the whole day looking for this, thanks a lot!

Comment: This worked for me too. I spent 3 days to decode when trying to implement a function in BigQuery to get base64 encoded gzipped string, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, do not use atob directly for decoding Base64 encoded zip files. You can use this  function mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21797381/3508516 instead.

```
function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
```