# Base64 decoding gives wrong result on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding

I want to decode a string. When I do it on PHP, Go, Python it gives different result than NodeJS. I tried a lot of base64 encoding/decoding libraries but result is always same. I spent 5 hours on this bug.

I want to decode this:

```
5wEoKBapCmDCaJrRCiwKFK1SIOQ8Y1K2V5UZbAOuNOhVgY+MEhQKBXVhdG9tEgsyMDA5OTAwMDAwMBIsChT59Ec6oQnuK5uLa1iNNvuWKdSOMBIUCgV1YXRvbRILMjAwOTkwMDAwMDASEwoNCgV1YXRvbRIEMTAwMBDAmgwaagom61rphyEDEfz4OLFOxWBL6HQbJLlw1nRE7zbfrXzYFJg8YIKC5fwSQAYqnpgwKpdJMx6L5ktYPYb7Lm81Xe2eXoRAloQQNKyhTvHaOBZzWGYSQSuWlMPxhJ9C4sxbeg1UN2lVJ8NLrYo=
```

When I decode it with Node result is:

```
�((�
`�h��
,
�R �<cR�W�l�4�U���
uatom
     20099000000,
��G:�   �+��kX�6��)Ԏ0
uatom
     20099000000

uatom1000��
           j
T7iU'�K��N�`K�t�p�tD�6߭|��<`����@*��0*�I3��KX=��.o5]�^�@��4��N��8sXfA+����B��[z
```

On the other languages like PHP, Python, Go result is:

```
?((?
`?h??
,
?R ?<cR?W?l?4?U???
uatom
     20099000000,
??G:?  ?+??kX?6??)Ԏ0
uatom
     20099000000

uatom1000??
           j
T7iU'?K??
```

What I have tried so far?
I tried built in Buffer:

```
Buffer.from("myData", 'base64').toString("utf-8")
```

I tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30106551/7886428
But it gives error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Looks like it's decoding the same way in Node but whatever you're using to display the output has a different encoding

Comment: Have you tried using js-base64 (https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64), specifically the `Base64.atob(encodedStr)` function call?  I tried it and while it is not the same as what your printing, it doesn't contain the � characters...

Comment: Phil I use macos terminal for both of the result. 
@DanielBank Yes it does not contain � characters but it is wrong. Even length of the result is different from other languages.