# How to create a compressed hash for my url in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, plugins

Hi i want to compress my url very similar to below shown **Result**

[image]

Here is above output link: https://jsbin.com/cayuhox/edit?html,css,js,output

**My Problem is** (i will be having most of the url as shown below, which not working with above generator):

1. [http://100.22.0.77:8888/nginx/assets?s={%22path%22:%22com://ANTARTICA%22,%22sort_by%22:0}&page=1&_=1595330210051](http://100.22.0.77:8888/nginx/assets?s=%7B%22path%22:%22com://ANTARTICA%22,%22sort_by%22:0%7D&page=1&_=1595330210051)
2. [http://100.22.0.77:8888/nginx/assets/folder_assets_counter?s={%22path%22:%22com%3A%2F%2FANTARTICA%22}&_=1595330210050](http://100.22.0.77:8888/nginx/assets/folder_assets_counter?s=%7B%22path%22:%22com%3A%2F%2FANTARTICA%22%7D&_=1595330210050)
3. 

```
 http://100.22.0.77:8888/nginx/assets/folder_assets_counter?s={"path":"com://ANTARTICA", selectedIds:["randeaee2d0af83b5cb4f86e","94ea39dc5eba3b41945d","ca49d38872e8b3f94758","6741e5d08fd18c7a69b3"]}&_=1595330210050
```

4. and even big url so on..

**Expected Output:**  i need to generate as short output as this one `woPCpXJvc2VzwqNyZWTCp3Zpb2xldHPCpGJsdWXCpmZydWnEkcKSwqVhcHDEjwI`  from above hash urls should not exceed 500 chars. i'm very much open to use any plugin or some of your tricky javascript code

Please help me thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you try using a library like https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string  and then compressing to b64?

Comment: @MihailFeraru, no i did not check that, but definitely i will check that, thanks for the info

Comment: @MihailFeraru, actually i tried that but it is generating something like this `઀낖ೠҕୠ伨ᣀ΀鰊愉誀癐˧꤁턀` kind of characters , but i don't want that kind of characters rather i want something this kind `GJsdWXCpmZydWnEkcKSwqVhcHDEjwI`

Comment: Did you encode the output using base64?

Comment: @MihailFeraru,  tried it is giving error `btoa('઀낖ೠҕୠ伨ᣀ΀鰊愉誀癐˧꤁턀')`  this error `Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.` in both case either `atob()` or `btoa()`

Comment: You need to convert it to raw bytes. Your current string is in UTF-16. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106476/using-javascripts-atob-to-decode-base64-doesnt-properly-decode-utf-8-strings