# scoping html data with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

This is my html ( in twig template )

```
<li id="{{folder.id}}" data-jstree='{"icon":"glyphicon glyphicon-tags", "type":"folder"}' ><a href="#">{{folder.name}}</a>
```

I am trying to get the value of 'type' from 'data-jstree'.

I tried using

```
var node_id = ref.get_node(sel[i]).id;
var type = $("#"+node_id).attr("data-jstree");
```

but that gives me this : {"icon":"glyphicon glyphicon-tag", "type":"tag"}
and i only need the value of type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $("#"+node_id).data("jstree").type

Comment: `var type = JSON.parse($("#"+node_id).attr("data-jstree")).type;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store JSON object in data attribute in HTML jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542746/store-json-object-in-data-attribute-in-html-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var type = JSON.parse($("#"+node_id).attr("data-jstree")).type
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to parse the string into json. do something like this:

```
var node_id = ref.get_node(sel[i]).id;
var type = $("#"+node_id).attr("data-jstree");
type = JSON.parse(type).type;
```