# Send data from Phoenix to Javascript in Slim template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, slim-lang

I have figured out a way to do this, defining a variable inside a HTML attribute like this:

```
div data-name=some_var id="component"
```

Then from Javascript I can retrieve it:

```
alert($("#component").data("name"));
```

However, it looks very ugly to me. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: The only other way is through a request (additional architectural considerations) or storing it in a cookie (additional code and complexity to retrieve the value). Although I do agree that theoretically it's a bit ugly having to embed data in the html for javascript consumption, it's the simplest way and I feel a bit better about it by using `meta` tags and removing the element from the DOM after it has been read in the front-end.

Comment: Ok, looks like this is the best solution for now, meta tags is a good idea if we have to use html tags anyway

Comment: you can also define a script tag that sets it on the `window` scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might feel dirty to you, but that's the most efficient way of sending data to the frontend from the backend. [In fact, it's pretty common.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Other ways of sending data would always involve making a separate web-request, which is usually unneeded in most cases.

---

And since you're using jQuery, it also abstracts away the implementation so you can send a pure JSON object in a `data-` attribute and can use it without having to parse it on the client-side.

```
div id='item' data-obj='{"foo":"bar"}'
```

and in your JS:

```
$('#item').data('obj') // {foo: bar}
```

---

Related resources:

- Stackoverflow: [Store JSON object in data attribute in HTML jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542746/store-json-object-in-data-attribute-in-html-jquery)
- MDN: [Use Data Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)
- Blog Post: [Using HTML 5 Data Attributes](http://blog.mitemitreski.com/2012/06/html-5-data-attributes-how-to-use-it.html)

Answer (score 1):

I usualy do it like this:

```
div id="component"
javascript:
  var templateData = {
    name: '<%= @name %>',
    product_str: '<%= Poison.encode!(@product) %>',
  };
```

You'll probably need to install [Poison](https://github.com/devinus/poison) to encode data to JSON.