# JS: Passed JSON-Array loses quotation marks

Tags: javascript, html, json

Basically I'm trying to pass an json-array via onclick to a function

```html
<button
  onclick='showAccountOverviewModal("<%= accounts[j].name %>", `<%= accounts[j].bills%>`)'>
  Click Me
</button>
```

But, when I try to parse the string via JSON.parse, I realize, that neither the keys, nor the values have quotation marks. Is there any 'good' way to fix this or do I need to use regular expressions?

Best regards

**EDIT**

This is the corresponding function:

```
function showAccountOverviewModal(accountName, accountBills) {
  $("#accountModalOverviewTitle").text(accountName);
  accountBills = JSON.parse(accountBills);
  console.log(accountBills);
  accountBills.forEach(bill => {
    console.log(bill);
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you show some of the `showAccountOverviewModal` function? It would be helpful to know how those arguments are used. What are you using to parse out the `<%=` constructs?

Comment: @TomHolmes Edited the code to provide more information

Comment: You have some ASP or EJS or something from which you are generating HTML with embedded JavaScript. **Look at the generated HTML**. Figure out what is wrong with it, then worry about how to change the ASP/EJS/whatever  to make it generate what you really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ill rewrite your code using data-* attribute. you can disregard if you dont want this approach.

html

```
<button class="showaccountmodal" 
data-accountName="<%= accounts[j].name %> 
data-bill="<%= accounts[j].bills %>">Click Me</button>
```

jquery

```
$(".showaccountmodal").on('click', function() {
var accountname = $(this).data('accountName');
var bill = $(this).data('bill');
console.log(accountname);
console.log(bill);
 accountBills.forEach(bill => {
    console.log(bill);
  });
} );
```

also here's a reference for storing json object in html [Store JSON object in data attribute in HTML jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542746/store-json-object-in-data-attribute-in-html-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you you may be passing a javascript array (already parsed) as opposed to a JSON array (a string representing the array). If so, prior to `JSON.parse`ing it, running

```
console.log(Array.isArray(accountBills))
```

should print `true`. If it is actually JSON, that would print `false` and running

```
console.log(typeof accountBills)
```

would print `string`.

If it is an array, then you don't need to parse it, and removing the `JSON.parse` line should make it work as expected.